# Html multiple selected dropdown showing first item selected by default

Tags: html, dropdown

[image]

I have made a drop down in which you can select multiple items but i want no item to be selected by default but when i come this page i get first item selected by default . I don't know how to set it as unselected at start.

Answer (score 0):

If you want no item to be selected you can just add this before your first option:

```
<option></option>
```

Update: For the multiple select: this should work fine

```
<select name="cars" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why not have all of them just unselected at the start. Isn't that possible?

Comment: What do you mean? Adding `<option></option>` in the beginning selects nothing from the options without having to use any javascript.

Comment: tried it , now i am getting both first and Islamabad Option as selected :p

Comment: sorry sorry , tried it , first option (empty) is not selected but islamabad still is O.o

Comment: yes i tried the same thing , it would have worked if was using a simple select but i am using <select multiple="multiple">

Comment: i have used the same thing on other page and it works fine but works different on my other page -_-
It's really weird

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select>
       <option disabled selected>  </option>
       <!-- Normal other options goes here -->
    </select>
```

Add this extra option.

[or]

If you have JQuery/JavaScript, do the following

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").selectedIndex = -1;

$("#dropdown").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

No you cannot do without an extra option/without JS/JQuery. It is the default behaviour of dropdown

Comment: what will this do??
and can u tell me the reason why this is happening , even firebug shows that it isn't selected by default but still it's selected when page loads :/

Comment: What did you try? Exxtra option or JS or JQuery and How?

Comment: tried this <option disabled selected>  </option>
with jquery this $("#nodes").prop("selectedIndex", -1);

Comment: Where did you add this option. As a first option?

Comment: ofcourse, i don't get it , why is this even selected by default . I didn't put any code for it to be selected -_-

Comment: Post an example to reproduce your issue